# How to create a generic object property updater using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to work out how to create a generic object property updater which is properly typed in TypeScript

```
const [originalObj, setOriginalObj] = useState<MyModel>(defaultModel)

const updateModelProp = <T extends keyof MyModel> (key: T, value: any) => {
  const newModel = { ...originalObj, [key]: value }
  setOriginalObj(newModel)
}
```

I have it working, other than the 'value' column, where I want it to use TypeScript to ensure you are using the correct type to the model provided.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How does your function must access to `originalObj`?

Comment: `value: MyModel[T]`

Comment: Thanks VLAZ, I thought I had tried that but obviously not, doh!

@p

Comment: You should probably create the newModel in a callback inside `setOriginalObj` to avoid closures... `setOriginalObj(prevModel => ({...prevModel, [key]: value}));`

Comment: @pilchard please can you give an example, this would really help my understanding